# Dropping content into textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to drag the content of the paragraph into the `textarea`. The text disappears when I try to drop it in the `textarea`. I want it to have the same behavior as the div with id `div1`

code

```js
function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  ev.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<br/>

<p id="drag1" draggable='true' ondragstart="drag(event)">
  here is some text foo-bar
</p>

<textarea class="textarea" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" placeholder="Drag and Drop image , Or paste image here" style="width: 810px; height: 200px"></textarea>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="event.preventDefault()"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

`ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));`

You don't want to append a child to the `textarea`, you want to set it's value. See belwo snippet.

```js
function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.value =(document.getElementById(data).innerText);
  ev.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<br/>

<p id="drag1" draggable='true' ondragstart="drag(event)">
  here is some text foo-bar
</p>

<textarea class="textarea" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" placeholder="Drag and Drop image , Or paste image here" style="width: 810px; height: 200px"></textarea>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="event.preventDefault()"></div>
```